# Wordpress ajax call returns entire page instead of just what I echo

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I've found a bunch of relevant other questions for this issue, but none of the are helping. I've simplified my code to the bare minimum for this exercise, but I just can't see what's wrong. I've checked the docs, multiple pages for like an hour... what the heck!?

In a template page, I have a jQuery block that calls Ajax:

```
// I still have no idea why I have to do this like this...
ajaxscript = { ajax_url :'<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>'}

$.ajax({ 
    url     : ajaxscript.ajaxurl,
    data    : {
                    'action'    : 'mark_lesson',
                    'postname'  : '<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>6'
                },
    method  : 'POST',
    success : function(output) {
        console.log(output);
        $(this).closest('.a_course').find('.read_it_check').addClass('checked');
        $('#yur_here').hide();
    },
    error : function(e) {
         console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Originally, I had the code for PHP in that same file, but that was dumb right? It goes in functions.php...doesn't it? Anyway, in functions.php:

```
/* Load Ajax Callback to "wp_ajax_*" Action Hook */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mark_lesson', 'mark_lesson' );

// Marks off lessons seen via AJAX
function mark_lesson(){
    global $wpdb;
    print_r($wpdb);
    echo 'suckit';
    exit(); // required. to end AJAX request.
    die();
    wp_die();
}
```

What's there to screw up here? There isn't even enough code to get it wrong, but it mysteriously returns an entire HTML page and NOT what I echo.

Comment: Jesus' answer below is spot on. Here's what's going on: your AJAX call is loading your current post (that's what your `// I still have no idea why I have to do this like this...` variable is doing). So, of course, the AJAX call returns the entire page. To call functions in your functions.php file, do what Jesus suggested (and make sure to [read the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), it'll save you and us time).

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have the issue with your `ajaxscript.ajaxurl` code, so try using this code below as your url.

```
// in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
}
```

for more info visit [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out I was just printing the wrong url. There's no need to localize anything when I can just php echo it directly into my JS.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a typo. I originally did it correctly then made a mistake when debugging by putting

```
<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>
```

Instead of:

```
<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>
```

There's no need to go through the complexity of localizing scripts or anything. I'm now feeding the admin-ajax url directly to the ajax function without the extra nonsense and it seems to be working.